# texelFetch works on NDIVIA driver but not on Mesa

Tags: linux, opengl, glsl

I have a 3D texture uploaded to a shader (see code below). I need to perform some bitwise operations on that texture to get bit-by-bit data. The Fragment shader I wrote works under Linux, with NVIDIA drivers given as

```
OpenGL version string: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 367.57
```

but do not work on another computer with Intel integrated GPU and Mesa drivers, version information given by:

```
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 11.2.0
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
```

What is the reason for this not to work on that system?
I know it supports `version 130`, and the compilation yields no errors.

What could be wrong, or, alternatively, how can I change this shader to NOT require `version 130`?

Here's the code:

```
        // Fragment Shader
        #version 130 \n
        \n
        in vec4 texcoord;\n
        \n
        uniform uint            width;\n
        uniform uint            height;\n
        uniform usampler3D textureA;\n
        \n
        void main() {\n
            uint x = uint(texcoord.x * float(width));\n
            uint y = uint(texcoord.y * float(height));\n
            uint shift = x % 8u;\n
            uint mask =  1u << shift;\n
            uint octet = texelFetch(textureA, ivec3(x / 8u, y % 256u, y  /256u), 0).r;
            uint value = (octet & mask) >> shift;\n         
            if (value > 0u)\n 
              gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);\n
            else\n
              gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);\n
        }
```